# How to pull the next available previous date?

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime

**What I have:**

I have table with a unique date column.

| id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-09-01 |
| 2 | 2021-08-01 |
| 3 | 2021-07-01 |
| 4 | 2020-04-01 |
| 5 | 2020-03-01 |
| 6 | 2020-12-01 |

I pull data based on a month and year from a GET parameter.

```
DB::table('budgets')->whereMonth('created_at', $request->get('month'))->whereYear('created_at', $request->get('year'))->get()->first();
```

I do a check to see if a previous month is available in table

```
$pm = DB::table('budgets')->whereMonth('created_at', $prev_month)->whereYear('created_at', $prev_year)->count();
if ($pm > 0) {
  $prev_month = date('m', strtotime($_GET['month']. ' - 1 month'));
  $prev_year = date('m', strtotime($_GET['month']. ' - 1 month'));
  <a href="{{ url('dashboard?month='.$prev_month.'&year='.$prev_year) }}">Previous Month</a>
}
```

This works great... if there is a previous month i.e. 1 month behind.

**My question is:**

How can I check what the nearest/next date is?

Example:

If I was already on '2021-07-01', how would I know the next 'previous' date is '2020-12-01' and visa versa?

Comment: You should not do this by trying to _calculate_ the previous year and month. Select the records with a date _lower_ than the one you are trying to find previous ones for, _order_ the result properly, and pick the first one of those.

Comment: @CBroe Much better logic, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution as per @CBroe advice:

```
<?php 
$this_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['month'].'-'.$_GET['year'].'-01'));
$pm = DB::table('budgets')->where('created_at', '<', $this_date)->orderby('created_at', 'desc')->get()->first(); // Find dates less than the one searching for and order it descending order and get only the first row.

if ($pm) {
  $prev_month = date('m', strtotime($pm->created_at));
  $prev_year = date('Y', strtotime($pm->created_at)); ?>

  <a href="{{ url('dashboard?month='.$prev_month.'&year='.$prev_year) }}">Previous Month</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the nearest/next date this way

```
$next_date = DB::table('budgets')
              ->where('created_at', '<', $date)
              ->orderByDesc('created_at')
              ->first()
              ->value('created_at');
```